# Uniform bounds on Kazhdan constants in groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, property-t

Does there exist a finitely generated discrete group $G$ such that it has property (T), but for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a generating set $S$ with the corresponding Kazhdan constant less than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: It seems so, by Gelander and Zuk http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=697297&vfpref=html&r=24&mx-pid=1910934

Comment: Yes,  "most" higher rank lattices have this property.

Comment: @Dan: thanks - can you give this comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, by Gelander and Zuk: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=697297&vfpref=html&r=24&mx-pid=1910934